# Обращение к процедуре с запросом на выборку

Tags: c#, sql

Помогите пожалуйста решить такую проблему:
Использую SQL запрос в процедуре:

```
cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT * from table where name IN (@name)";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", calcname);
```

На форме создал  `checkedListBox`, в котором вписал те значения которые должны удовлетворять условию.
Теперь при обращении к процедуре (с запросом) пытаюсь подставить выбранные значения из `checkedListBox` (при обращении вместо [[[@name](/users/861/namespace)](/users/861/namespace)](/users/861/namespace) подставляю Text)

```
        string Text = "";
        foreach (string z in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
         Text += "'" + z + "'" + ",  ";
        Text = Text.Substring(0, Text.Length - 2);//обрезаем последний пробел
```

Но выборка не идет. Подскажите, как мне сделать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что Вы в качестве параметра запроса передаёте строку, в которую записан весь список. Получается, что в операторе IN у Вас одно значение, а не множество.

Для начала можете попробовать убрать параметр запроса и менять прямо его текст.

А вообще, по-хорошему, для каждой выбранной галочки надо создавать свой параметр и передавать туда выбранное этой галочкой значение.

Т.е., в любом случае, Вам необходимо в зависимости от выбора пользователя варьировать сам текст запроса. Или, как вариант, использовать табличный параметр, но это уже имхо из пушки по воробьям.